# Laradock virtual host not working on mac monterey apache2

Tags: docker, apache, vhosts, laradock

I have read many posts on the subject but none refers to exactly the same environment I have (Mac OS Monterey).  So what I have done so far...

I have successfully installed the latest versions of Docker & LaraDock with apache2.  I have phpMyAdmin working fine at localhost:8081.  Then I followed the docs and some tutorial to set up laradock for multiproject.

I successfuly created a laravel9 project (ProjectA) inside the workspace container.  I can view the website in the browser at localhost/ProjectA/public.

I want to create a virtual host for ProjectA to be able to type projectA.test in the browser and point to localhost/ProjectA/public.

So again, I followed the instructions on Laradock and edited the laradock/apache2/sites/default.apache.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName laradock.test
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

  <Directory "/Users/Sites">
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and created a laradock/sites/projectA.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName projectA.test
  DocumentRoot /var/www/projectA/public
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

  <Directory "/var/www/projectA/public">
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Even after restarting apache2 in Docker, projectA.test does not display the correct website but point to the root.

In the folder apache2 there is a file called vhost.conf with Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf.  When I copied the 2 conf files above into that folder (which was not there before), I get a Forbidden error : You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at utopia.test Port 80.

After reading an article on apache error 403, I change the permission on the public folder to be:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 public
sudo chown -R _www:_www public

drwxrwxr-x@ 15 _www  _www      480 Mar 19 18:11 public
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help please.

Answer (score 1):

I was so tired with this issue that I forgot to restart Apache after changing permission... that was the trick!

I hope this will help others as I did not find this solution in any of the tutorials or posts on the subject!